# Device File Sharing Across Routers

Tags: networking, router, file-sharing

I've read through and implemented all the similar questions but none seem to work under my situation, or im missing something. My home netwrk is setup as in the image below. Basically I have a router/modem from my provider (Router A) and it is a no name brand with terrible wifi at IP address 192.168.1.1. With an ethernet cable I've connected it to my TV and a USB drive to the router. This works amazingly, TV can access the USB files no problem.

I've then connected router A to router B (fritzbox with good wifi) with an ethernet cable to a LAN port and my desktop PC to router B with an ethernet cable. Router B IP address on router A is 192.168.1.27 and Router B IP address for "itself" is 192.168.188.1. From my desktop PC I can access router settings of both router A and B no problem, and internet works well.

The problem is I would like to update the files on the USB drive with my desktop PC, but it cant seem to see the USB drive with the addres provided by router a (\192.168.1.1\MyUSB). Surely this must be possble? I can access it by connecting to router A wifi but the connection keeps dropping and its irritating so much so that its easier to eject the usb and physically plug it into my desktop PC.

I assumed it had to do with DHCP, but i cant see how i can force router B to not assign an IP to my PC it has and it keeps it as such even after a restart. When trying to connect to the USB it saysing something wrong with port xx not sure if that helps?

PLease any shove in the right direction would be apprciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put everything on ONE subnet. Works so much better.

**Router B:**

Reset to factory defaults.
Hook up a LAN port on Router B to a LAN port on Router A.

Give Router B a static IP address on A:  192.168.1.10 or like (not inside the DHCP scope of A).

Turn DHCP OFF on Router B. You only want ONE DHCP setup and that is on Router A.

Once done, set up WiFi on A or B as desired.

This will work reliably and over time. My setup has been running like this for years. Printing on all devices and file sharing works fine. File sharing is a workstation setup.